# Select columns in 3 tables if it is null or not

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am learning more in PL/SQL Toad for Oracle. I want to select some columns in 3 tables and then I use **case** statements to execute if it is Null or Not. This is my sample script.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN a.column1 is NULL
             THEN 'Active'
             ELSE 'Inactive'
             END) as Status_Define_Resources, <<some columns>>,

       (CASE WHEN b.column1 is NULL
             THEN 'ACTIVE'
             ELSE 'INACTIVE'
             END) as STATUS_USER, <<some columns>>,

                   c.LASTNAME, c.FIRSTNAME, c.MIDDLENAME

FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
```

It is running.. my problem is I want to combine column names `c.LASTNAME`, `c.FIRSTNAME` and `c.MIDDLENAME` any ideas? And sorry I am new in Toad for Oracle PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Concatenation`. [Here's](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0040__Query-Select/MergingColumnOutputUsingConcatenation.htm) a example.

But in your case

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN a.column1 is NULL
         THEN 'Active'
         ELSE 'Inactive'
         END) as Status_Define_Resources, <<some columns>>,

   (CASE WHEN b.column1 is NULL
         THEN 'ACTIVE'
         ELSE 'INACTIVE'
         END) as STATUS_USER, <<some columns>>,

    c.LASTNAME||','||c.FIRSTNAME||','||c.MIDDLENAME as "Complete Name"

FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
```

I assume the 3 tables are related by a `Foreign Key` then used [Join Statements](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/Catalog0140__Table-Joins.htm)

Comment: Thank you. "||" means what sir?

Comment: symbol for concatenate

Comment: Ok so it means to join columns. Thank you again.